# ubuntu. How run echo script in cron?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, htop

I want to log my system from htop.

How run this script in cron?

```
echo q | htop | aha --black --line-fix > htop.html
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: check how cron works and you will get it.